# Trying to routes using id of the product but url is upadated but routing is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using react router dom for redirect components but not working only url change showing nothing.
Trying to routes according to id and displaying details of items

```
App.js:

import "./styles.css";
import Food from "./components/food";
import ProductDetail from "./components/ProductDetail";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={Food} />
        <Route exact path="/ProductDetail:id" component={ProductDetail} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}



food.jsx:

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { data } from '../data/data';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';


const Food = () => {
  //   console.log(data);
  const [foods, setFoods] = useState(data);

  //   Filter Type burgers/pizza/etc
  const filterType = (category) => {
    setFoods(
      data.filter((item) => {
        return item.category === category;
      })
    );
  };

  //   Filter by price
  const filterPrice = (price) => {
    setFoods(
      data.filter((item) => {
        return item.price === price;
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className='max-w-[1640px] m-auto px-4 py-12'>
      <h1 className='text-orange-600 font-bold text-4xl text-center'>
        Top Rated Menu Items
      </h1>

      {/* Filter Row */}
      <div className='flex flex-col lg:flex-row justify-between'>
        {/* Fliter Type */}
        <div>
          <p className='font-bold text-gray-700'>Filter Type</p>
          <div className='flex justfiy-between flex-wrap'>
            <button
              onClick={() => setFoods(data)}
              className='m-1 border-orange-600 text-orange-600 hover:bg-orange-600 hover:text-white'
            >
              All
            </button>
            <button
              onClick={() => filterType('burger')}
              className='m-1 border-orange-600 text-orange-600 hover:bg-orange-600 hover:text-white'
            >
              Burgers
            </button>
            <button
              onClick={() => filterType('pizza')}
              className='m-1 border-orange-600 text-orange-600 hover:bg-orange-600 hover:text-white'
            >
              Pizza
            </button>
            <button
              onClick={() => filterType('salad')}
              className='m-1 border-orange-600 text-orange-600 hover:bg-orange-600 hover:text-white'
            >
              Salads
            </button>
            <button
              onClick={() => filterType('chicken')}
              className='m-1 border-orange-600 text-orange-600 hover:bg-orange-600 hover:text-white'
            >
              Chicken
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>

        {/* Filter Price */}
        <div>
          <p className='font-bold text-gray-700'>Filter Price</p>
          <div className='flex justify-between max-w-[390px] w-full'>
            <button
              onClick={() => filterPrice('$')}
              className='m-1 border-orange-600 text-orange-600 hover:bg-orange-600 hover:text-white'
            >
              $
            </button>
            <button
              onClick={() => filterPrice('$$')}
              className='m-1 border-orange-600 text-orange-600 hover:bg-orange-600 hover:text-white'
            >
              $$
            </button>
            <button
              onClick={() => filterPrice('$$$')}
              className='m-1 border-orange-600 text-orange-600 hover:bg-orange-600 hover:text-white'
            >
              $$$
            </button>
            <button
              onClick={() => filterPrice('$$$$')}
              className='m-1 border-orange-600 text-orange-600 hover:bg-orange-600 hover:text-white'
            >
              $$$$
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      {/* Display foods */}
      <div className='grid grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-6 pt-4'>
        {foods.map((item, index) => (
          <div
            key={index}
            className='border shadow-lg rounded-lg hover:scale-105 duration-300'
          >
            <img
              src={item.image}
              alt={item.name}
              className='w-full h-[200px] object-cover rounded-t-lg'
            />
            <div className='flex justify-between px-2 py-4'>
              <p className='font-bold'>{item.name}</p>
              <p>
                <span className='bg-orange-500 text-white p-1 rounded-full'>
                  {item.price}
                </span>
              </p>
              <NavLink to={`/foods/${item.id}`}>Buy Now</NavLink>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Food;

data.jsx:

export const data = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Double Cheeseburger',
      category: 'burger',
      image:
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1607013251379-e6eecfffe234?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8YnVyZ2Vyc3xlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1400&q=60',
      price: '$$$$',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Bacon Cheeseburger',
      category: 'burger',
      image:
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553979459-d2229ba7433b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTh8fGJ1cmdlcnN8ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1400&q=60',
      price: '$',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Mushroom Burger',
      category: 'burger',
      image:
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1608767221051-2b9d18f35a2f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTV8fGJ1cmdlcnN8ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1400&q=60',
      price: '$$',
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'Loaded Burger',
      category: 'burger',
      image:
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1568901346375-23c9450c58cd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NHx8YnVyZ2Vyc3xlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1400&q=60',
      price: '$$$',
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: 'Feta & Spinnach',
      category: 'pizza',
      image:
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593560708920-61dd98c46a4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8OHx8cGl6emF8ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60',
      price: '$$',
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      name: 'Supreme Pizza',
      category: 'pizza',
      image:
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1604382355076-af4b0eb60143?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8N3x8cGl6emF8ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60',
      price: '$$$',
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      name: 'Meat Lovers',
      category: 'pizza',
      image:
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1628840042765-356cda07504e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTh8fHBpenphfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60',
      price: '$$$$',
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      name: 'Cheese Pizza',
      category: 'pizza',
      image:
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1548369937-47519962c11a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8OXx8Y2hlZXNlJTIwcGl6emF8ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60',
      price: '$',
    },
    {
      id: 9,
      name: 'Kale Salad',
      category: 'salad',
      image:
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1515543237350-b3eea1ec8082?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8c2FsYWQlMjBjZWFzYXJ8ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60',
      price: '$$',
    },
    {
      id: 10,
      name: 'Ceasar Salad',
      category: 'salad',
      image:
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1546793665-c74683f339c1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NHx8c2FsYWQlMjBjZWFzYXJ8ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60',
      price: '$$$',
    },
    {
      id: 11,
      name: 'Loaded Salad',
      category: 'salad',
      image:
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1540420773420-3366772f4999?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8c2FsYWR8ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60',
      price: '$$$$',
    },
    {
      id: 12,
      name: 'Fruit Salad',
      category: 'salad',
      image:
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564093497595-593b96d80180?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NHx8ZnJ1aXQlMjBzYWxhZHxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60',
      price: '$',
    },
    {
      id: 13,
      name: 'Wings',
      category: 'chicken',
      image:
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1567620832903-9fc6debc209f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8Y2hpY2tlbiUyMGZvb2R8ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60',
      price: '$$',
    },
    {
      id: 14,
      name: 'Baked Chicken',
      category: 'chicken',
      image:
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1594221708779-94832f4320d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8Y2hpY2tlbiUyMGZvb2R8ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60',
      price: '$$$$',
    },
    {
      id: 15,
      name: 'Chicken Tenders',
      category: 'chicken',
      image:
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1562967914-608f82629710?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTB8fGNoaWNrZW4lMjBmb29kfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60',
      price: '$',
    },
    {
      id: 16,
      name: 'Chicken Kabob',
      category: 'chicken',
      image:
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1603360946369-dc9bb6258143?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTN8fGNoaWNrZW4lMjBmb29kfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60',
      price: '$$$',
    },
  ];
  
  export const categories = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Fast Food',
      image:
        'https://duyt4h9nfnj50.cloudfront.net/new_search_home_eats_icon/FastFood_BrowseHome@3x.png',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Pizza',
      image:
        'https://duyt4h9nfnj50.cloudfront.net/new_search_home_eats_icon/Pizza_BrowseHome@3x.png',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Wings',
      image:
        'https://duyt4h9nfnj50.cloudfront.net/new_search_home_eats_icon/Wings_BrowseHome@3x.png',
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'Indian',
      image:
        'https://duyt4h9nfnj50.cloudfront.net/new_search_home_eats_icon/Indian_BrowseHome@3x.png',
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: 'Latest Deals',
      image:
        'https://duyt4h9nfnj50.cloudfront.net/new_search_home_eats_icon/Deals_BrowseHome@3x.png',
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      name: 'Restaurant Rewards',
      image:
        'https://duyt4h9nfnj50.cloudfront.net/new_search_home_eats_icon/RestoRewards_BrowseHome@3x.png',
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      name: 'Best Overall',
      image:
        'https://duyt4h9nfnj50.cloudfront.net/new_search_home_eats_icon/TopEats_Browse%20Home@3x.png',
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      name: 'Shipped Free',
      image:
        'https://duyt4h9nfnj50.cloudfront.net/new_search_home_eats_icon/Placeholder_Plates@3x.png',
    },
  ];
```

Here CodeSandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-ride-e705w9?file=/src/App.js

I am trying to routing according to id and display details